# Jquery Masonry images stacked on top of page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, masonry

I have masonry layouts on my website, but when I load the page, the images "pile up" on top of each other. When you reload the page a couple of times it gets better,  but still doesn't display as it should. Here is the link to a page displaying the masonry images. http://vanillaphotography.co.za/weddings/

However, I am not finding any errors, and this has been a big headache for months. I used the ImagesLoaded plugin to fix this same issue, but now even that doesn't work.

Here is my jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

/******/
//masonry
var $container = $('.portfolio_container');
// initialize Masonry after all images have loaded  
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  $('.portfolio_container').fadeIn();
  $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: 278,
      itemSelector: '.masonry-entry'
    });
});

// infinitescroll() is called on the element that surrounds 
// the items you will be loading more of
  $('.portfolio_container').infinitescroll({

    navSelector  : ".navigation",            
                   // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    nextSelector : ".navigation a:first",    
                   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : ".portfolio_container .masonry-entry"          
                   // selector for all items you'll retrieve

  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
     var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).hide(); // hide to begin with

     $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $newElems.fadeIn(); // fade in when ready
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
    });
  });

//jQuery(".masonry-entry").find('img').parent().parent().parent().addClass('white');
    jQuery(".single-format-standard .entry-content img").wrap("<div class='img-wrap'></div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in main.js, try the code below.

Replace this

```
//masonry
    var $container = $('.portfolio_container');
    // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded  
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      $('.portfolio_container').fadeIn();
      $container.masonry({
          columnWidth: 278,
          itemSelector: '.masonry-entry'
        });
    });
```

With

```
$(function(){

    var $container = $('.portfolio_container');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.masonry();
    });


});
```

Comment: Its a long shot but try the above code, if it works then there is something wrong with the version of masonry you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work. It makes no difference to the display of the images.

Comment: Well it looks like it is working fine now, The images are not aligned but that might be due to the size of the images, but the stacking issue has gone. i am also not seeing the javascript error now.